# How to enable auto-completion in SQL Workbench/J

Tags: oracle, sqlclient, sql-workbench-j

How do I enable auto completion feature so that SQL Workbench/J automatically completes the code. For example, If I alias a table in query then using that alias with a period should show the columns present in table.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I prefer using MySQL Workbench, but here is how you can turn auto-complete in SQL Workbench/J,
here you will use the combination of some options to do this takse,

**First**, in your Menu Bar -> SQL:

```
SQL -> Settings -> 
1- Check: Auto Advance to next
2- Check: Detect prepared statements
```

**Second**, in your Menu Bar -> Tools:

```
Tools -> Options ->
1- Check: Close completion with search
2- check: QuickSearch matches anywhere
```

**Finally**, you can **Ctrl + Space** and you will see the magic auto-completion
I will provide some screenshots of mine, also you can check out the manual at [Manual](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/editor.html#command-completion)
Please hit vote up if I have solved your problem :)

[image: Image02]
[image: Image03]
[image: Image05]

Answer (score 1):

[Preferences screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOVDt.png)

In  Preferences: SQL Editor: Query Editor

Check  *Enable Code Completion in Editors* and *Automatically Start Code Completion*

Comment: I think you got confused between two different tools. SQL Workbench and SQL Workbench/J are two different tools. But thanks for your answer, I was able to find similar option in SQL Workbench/J as well now.

Comment: @conetfun oh sorry, my friend. Thank you for understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this option under SQL > Auto Completion

Default shortcut for MAC is CTRL+SPACE

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM86X.jpg